# How to swap the lines in a file that match a condition using Shell script

Tags: unix, match, conditional-statements, swap, lines

I have a file in which 28th character of every line is either "A" or "D".
I want to swap the lines in such a way that the first line of the file should have the 28th character as "D" and the 
second line of the file should have 28 the character as "A".
And the pattern should continue through out the file.

Input file:

```
00254920141228N201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
00254920141228N201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
00254920141228R201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
00254920141228R201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
00254920141228R201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
00254920141228R201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
```

Output should be:

```
00254920141228N201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
00254920141228N201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
00254920141228R201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
00254920141228R201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
00254920141228R201412251850D201412200050SA1150TH1850000
00254920141228R201412251850A201412241740SA1118WE1440SCL
```

I want the script to be written in Unix shell script.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? Why does your  sample data have A but your question Ä?

Comment: Sample data is correct. Every line 28th character is either A or D. I have written a logic using SED, but it didn't work. Can you provide your suggestion to proceed further.

Comment: Post your `sed` script ([edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30553286/edit) the question to include it) and explain what's wrong with it. See the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section for detailed posting guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Python script which implements what I think you are trying to describe.

```
from sys import stdin
keep = "A"
kept = []
for line in stdin:
    line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
    pattern = line[27:28]
    # print("## keep %s, pattern %s, %s" % (keep, pattern, line))
    if pattern != keep:
        if len(kept) > 0:
            print line
            # print("### len kept == %i, popping" % len(kept))
            print kept.pop(0)
        else:
            # print("### no kept, just print")
            print line
            keep = pattern
    else:
        # print("### keeping for later")
        keep = pattern
        kept.append(line)
if len(kept) > 1:
    raise ValueError("Too many %s lines" % keep)
elif len(kept) == 1:
    print kept[0]
```

I left my debug prints in so you can hopefully see what's happening -- uncomment the print statements with `#` in them to get a bit of debug diagnostics if it doesn't do exactly what you want.

I actually started writing this as an Awk script for simplicity, but Awk arrays don't have push/pop, so it turned out more complex than I liked.

I would not use `sed` for this.  I don't doubt that it's doable, but it will be hard to maintain, especially if not you and all your colleagues are committing to maintaining a high fluency in `sed`.  (That's a nicer way to say "write-only language"...)

I consistently used double quotes for all the Python strings.  That way, you can embed it single-quoted in a simple shell script for testing, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -c '... text
of
script' <<':'
sample
data
:
```

Comment: I originally wrote this to maintain the order of the input as far as possible, then flip-flop only when the input appears out of order; change the first assignment to `keep = None` to restore this behavior.  Your question specifically asks for the first line to have D, i.e. for any A lines to be kept for later at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your script. I am new to Python, but i will be able to run the python script from my solaris environment. Do i need to give the input file as an argument ?

Comment: I have too many lines similar to the sample data, when i execute the complete file it is throwing the below error.                                             + 0<<
  File "<string>", line 23
    raise ValueError("Too many %s lines" % keep)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block.

Comment: For the resolution of Intendation error, i have given SHIFT+TAB in my code, then the error disappeared, But now i am facing a new error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
ValueError: Too many A lines .

Comment: The script doesn't know what to do if there is an unconsumed queue of kept lines which were never paired up with a D line when the input ended. I coded it to complain in this case. If you can specify what should happen instead, I can update it.

Comment: Pair up should be done based on first six character's of every line. If the first six character matches then pairing of A and D can be done. If not we need to leave that particular line and need to go for next line.

Comment: This is a completely new requirement! Maybe you should just accept this answer and post a new question with what you *actually* want.